# Getting data from HTML into Javascript (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using [jsGrid](http://js-grid.com/) to display data from a database. I want to avoid a lot of copy paste code and would like to create one of the grids for each `<div>` with a certain id and pass along some other corresponding values if that is possible.

I guess it is best to illustrate what I want to accomplish by giving this code sample:

```
function gridfunction(){

   $("#jsgrididvalue").jsGrid({
       var one = new Array ('red', 'green', 'brown');
       var two = new Array ('car', 'bus');
       var variable = "good";
       //the grid jscode is omitted here
   })

   $("#jsgrididvaluetwo").jsGrid({
       var one = new Array ('red', 'green', 'brown');
       var two = new Array ('orange', 'yellow', 'blue');
       var variable = "bad";
       //the grid jscode is omitted again
   })

}
```

Now, I don't know if it is possible but I was hoping that adding something like

```
<div id="jsgrididvalue" arrayone="red, green, brown" arraytwo="car, bus" something="good"></div>
<div id="jsgrididvaluetwo" arrayone="orange, yellow, blue" arraytwo="train, plane" something="bad"></div>
```

instead of just

```
<div id="jsgrididvalue"></div>
<div id="jsgrididvaluetwo"></div>
```

would help me to get where I want to be. I was experimenting with `getElementbyID` and some other things but couldn't get anything to work. I would appreciate it very much if somebody could point me in the right direction or tell me if something like this is at all possible. Needless to say that I'm at the beginning of learning javascript.

Comment: It's only `var arrayone = $("#jsgrididvalue").attr("arrayone");` to put `arrayone` attribute-value of id `jsgrididvalue` into `arrayone` variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could improve NOBrien's answer by this:

```
<div class="jsGridItem" id="jsgrididvalue" data-arrayone="red,green,brown" data-arraytwo="car,bus" data-something="good"></div>
<div class="jsGridItem" id="jsgrididvaluetwo" data-arrayone="orange,yellow,blue" data-arraytwo="train,plane" data-something="bad"></div>`
```

Then you can call for each element that contains that class:

```
function gridfunction(){
    $(".jsGridItem").each(function(){
       var one = $(this).data('arrayone').split(',');
       var two = $(this).data('arraytwo').split(',');
       var variable = $(this).data('something');

       $(this).jsGrid({
           fields: []//use your data 
       });
       //the grid jscode is omitted here
   })
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the effort. You seem to have forgotten the function part in each though. If you add that, I will accept the answer.

Comment: `$(".jsGridItem").each({` gives an unexpected identifier error. If you go `$(".jsGridItem").each(function(){` it works fine.

Comment: ohh OMG I can't believe I forgot to type it hahahhaah

Comment: Thanks hahaaha Sometimes I just type without test... but you got the point I meant.. that the goal ;)

Comment: I'm grad my answer helped you ;)

Answer (score 1):

html:

```
<div id="jsgrididvalue" arrayone="red,green,brown" arraytwo="car,bus" something="good"></div>
<div id="jsgrididvaluetwo" arrayone="orange,yellow,blue" arraytwo="train,plane" something="bad"></div>
```

**you need to replace spaces of `arrayone` attribute value above**
javascript:

```
function gridfunction(){

   $("#jsgrididvalue").jsGrid({
       var one = $(this).attr("arrayone").split(",");
       var two = $(this).attr("arrayone").split(",");
       var variable = $(this).attr("something");
       //the grid jscode is omitted here
   })

   $("#jsgrididvaluetwo").jsGrid({
       var one = $(this).attr("arrayone").split(",");
       var two = $(this).attr("arrayone").split(",");
       var variable = $(this).attr("something");
       //the grid jscode is omitted again
   })

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add your custom attributes as data elements to your divs (removing the spaces in the array lists)

```
<div class="jsGridItem" id="jsgrididvalue" data-arrayone="red,green,brown" data-arraytwo="car,bus" data-something="good"></div>
<div class="jsGridItem" id="jsgrididvaluetwo" data-arrayone="orange,yellow,blue" data-arraytwo="train,plane" data-something="bad"></div>`
```

and a common class to both.  Then you can grab through both at once:

```
function gridfunction(){
    $(".jsGridItem").jsGrid({
       var one = $(this).data('arrayone').split(',');
       var two = $(this).data('arraytwo').split(',');
       var variable = $(this).data('something');
       //the grid jscode is omitted here
   })
}
```

Comment: This is the object of options the jsGrid expects.. I couldn't just adding code inside it.

Comment: Are you saying that you can't change the array info to data attributes, or you can't add the class?

Comment: The object of options are expecting attributes inside, not code!

Comment: You can see on [Docs](http://js-grid.com/docs/#configuration) what this object arg expects